# Htaccess access/download

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

Using htaccess I'm basically trying to forbid access to the page i.e http://example.com, but it will still allow people to download files if they have a direct link i.e http://example.com/hi.zip.

I'm using the directory directive to display the basic download page. According to [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_autoindex.html) **mod_autoindex.c** is used,so basically what I'm trying to do is:

```
<Files mod_autoindex.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Example"
    AuthUserFile "/home/.htpasswd"
    require valid-user
</Files>
```

Any advice/tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work (tested on my webserver: www.gopeter.de/test is restricted, www.gopeter.de/test/test.zip is allowed)

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Restricted Directory" 
AuthUserFile /path/to/directory/.htpasswd 
require valid-user

<FilesMatch "\.(gz|pdf|zip|rar)$" >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to restrict access to the home page or all pages except allowed files would be to add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not one of the allowed files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(hi|file1|file2)\.zip[NC] 
#return a 403 forbidden
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```