# htaccess for download directory

Tags: .htaccess, download

I have a folder where I want to keep some downloadable items, but I don't want people to be able to navigate directly to that url.  I set up htaccess so that it is password protected which works fine.  The problem is I want a user to be able to click a download link and download an item from that folder without having to enter a password.  Whats the best way to secure the folder while still allowing downloads from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, it would still restrict the download links.

I did find this answer which solved the problem:  [Htaccess access/download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119984/htaccess-access-download)

I had to use

```
<FilesMatch "\.(.+)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is little tricky. Let's assume your download folder is names as `DocumentRoot/downloads`

You can use this code in your `/downloads/.htaccess`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/downloads/.+$" ALLOWED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /Ful/Path/To/passwords
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
Satisfy any
```

1. This will allow **unrestricted access** to any file inside `/downloads`/ folder.
2. This will show basic auth popup when user enters `http://domain.com/downloads/`