# OctoberCMS | How do I enable a directory for download in OctoberCMS?

Tags: octobercms

I'm using XAMPP, and I need to enable a directory for download.
I tried to give file permissions via FTP with FileZilla, but it didn't work.

I've seen this post, but didn't work for me: [htaccess for download directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979765/htaccess-for-download-directory)

`themes/mytheme/uploads/`         **  If I try to access **file.pdf** saved here (via url)  I get 'File not found'

`themes/mytheme/assets/images/`   ** OK, I can download my **file.pdf** from this  url

If I save the following **.htaccess** under /**uploads** , I still get 'File not found'

```
<FilesMatch "\.(.+)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

It seems October prevent direct access to certain directories from the url.

This is the original **.htaccess** from the web root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


   ## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  ## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>
```

How do I access a file saved under **/uploads** ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm its quite easy

```
##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*

====> Do you see this line ^

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

> Replace that line with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources|uploads)/.*
                 ====> we are adding our folder to allow access  ^
```

> It basically tells server that what files are in `assets|resources|uploads` let them allow access and let them download, instead just redirecting them to `index.php`

It should solve your issue

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks Hardik I've learned something about .htaccess